# Wordpress Media Thumbnail/Permalink

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, media, permalinks

I have an issue with my Wordpress installation. I dont know when it happened so maybe someone can help me to find the problem.

Suddenly all my media thumbs are missing. recreation gives me an error. when uploading new files, thumbnails and links are created properly. Permalinks to the imagefiles are broken but i can use the images placed on my website (direct link/gallery). Permalink of broken files is set to WP root.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question it looks that you are making a copy of your website in to new server.

If so then please make sure 2 things.

1. You have copied your uploads folder.
2. You have replaced all older link by new link in DB.

Comment: Hi. Maybe something went wrong with my installation but i didnt move the installation. But maybe i will have to check the links in my DB or i even thought about reuploading the files.